# BASIC : POKE and PEEK prohibited on the same line?

Tags: basic, 8-bit-microcomputers

Having been raised on an 8-bit Commodore, I was never afraid of PEEKs and POKEs.

I remember trying to accomplish something on a computer, in BASIC, using PEEKs and POKEs, and discovering that this particular BASIC didn't allow use of a PEEK and a POKE on the same line of code. You could use a PEEK() or a POKE, but not both. So, for a read-and-modify operation, an intermediate variable was needed.

My recollection is that this was on a friend's TRS-80 Color Computer. However, I've tried this online on CoCo emulators and there is no such constraint, I can do POKE 5120, PEEK(5120)+1 without errors.

What other platform could it have been? Or did I dream all this? As a nerdy teenager with a few friends, I had access to many "home" computers around 1984-87, from a Radio Shack PC-2 pocket thingy to an IBM PC XT. I live in Canada, so it wasn't something exotic like a BBC or Oric.

Comment: I believe I've seen one or two small, simple implementations of BASIC that only allow one command per line, but I can't remember which ones and I doubt this is what you encountered.

Comment: @TimLocke Which wouldn'T matter here, as PEEK isn't a command, but a function, so even Tiny-BASIC's [that add PEEK/POKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_BASIC#Deviations_from_the_design) allow to use PEEK existing on the same line as POKE, being used as parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first version of Commodore Basic (the so called "old ROMs" or "original ROMs" or similar) did have a limitation that `PEEK` and `POKE` used the same temporary storage for the memory address. As a result it would `POKE` into the wrong location:

```
*** COMMODORE BASIC ***

 7167 BYTES FREE

READY.
POKE 0,3

READY.
POKE 1,PEEK(0)+1

READY.
? PEEK(0);PEEK(1)
 4  48

READY.
```

This problem would most likely also be present in other early Microsoft BASIC versions.

It is fixed in, at least, later versions from Commodore:

```
### COMMODORE BASIC ###

 31743 BYTES FREE

READY.
POKE 0,3

READY.
POKE 1,PEEK(0)+1

READY.
? PEEK(0);PEEK(1)
 3  4

READY.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I remembered. Although I never used a 1977 PET, I may have read a programming book or article for Commodore machines that warned about this quirk and advised not to combine PEEK and POKE in the same statement to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 7):

On the TI-99/4A in TI-BASIC with [mini-memory](https://www.ninerpedia.org/wiki/Mini_Memory) module you couldn't put [CALL LOAD](https://www.ninerpedia.org/wiki/Programming#Useful_CALL_LOADs) (which includes the functionality of `POKE` even if it does more than that) and `CALL PEEK` on the same line as TI-BASIC didn't allow for multiple statements on one LINE. `CALL PEEK`  was not a function as PEEK is on all other basics. Its syntax was `CALL PEEK(adress, var1[,...,varn])`. The same is true for the `CALL POKEV/CALL PEEKV` statements that did POKE/PEEK in video memory.

In TI-extended BASIC with memory expansion there also was `CALL PEEK` and `CALL LOAD` but as it lifted the 1 statement per line restriction of TI-BASIC there could be more than one `CALL PEEK/LOAD` per line.

Comment: I have a hard time to see a `CALL LOAD` as a poke equivalent, as I do remember it more complex. A usage to flip around bits according to program flow, like common with other BASIC, might create issues - IIRC.

Comment: https://www.ninerpedia.org/wiki/Programming#Useful_CALL_LOADs
CALL LOAD(addr, val1...valn) when used with numeric parameters is a POKE. If one of the parameter is a file handle (DSK1.DEMO) it loads the object file at that address.
http://www.mainbyte.com/ti99/software/s_carts/mini.html

Answer (score 1):

> POKE and PEEK prohibited on the same line?

### No ...

There is no such restriction in any somewhat standard BASIC, as it would go against how BASIC works. Lines function only to handle source during editing, and to allow walking them at runtime for sequence and serve as `GOTO` / `GOSUB` targets. They do not form any construct of execution bracket.

Any language doing so would not be BASIC (*1).

Execution in BASIC rather simple and straightforward:

- Lines are executed in sequence.
- Statements in a line are executed in sequence.
- `POKE` is a statement. It will be executed when parsed without any relations to prior (*2,3) or later statements, or any expressions within.
- Any statement executed may have parameters.
- All parameters will be evaluated in sequence left to right.
- Parameters may be (and usually are) expressions.
- `PEEK` is a function.
- Functions can be used as (part of) an expression.

Thus when in a program like:

```
10 FOR I = 768 to 783
20 POKE I, PEEK(I+1)
30 NEXT I
40 POKE 784, 0
```

line `20` is executed, `POKE` will:

- Evaluate the first parameter `I` as the target.

  - Evaluation returns the content of `I`.
- Evaluate the second parameter as the value.

  - Doing so includes calling the function `PEEK`, which:

    - Evaluates `I+1` as its target.
    - Fetches the content of that location.
    - Returns whatever that is.
- Then `POKE` will use both (target, value) to store value at target.

As a result that program will move all bytes from `0301h..030Fh` to `0300h..030Eh` (*4). What else :)

---

### ... But

there is one somewhat known exceptional version of PEEK in [TI Extended BASIC](https://www.digitpress.com/library/manuals/ti994a/ti%20extended%20basic.pdf). TI BASIC did not implement any PEEK or POKE function or command, as the concept of that machine is more advanced than your average home computer, allowing a closer integration (*5). With Extended BASIC `PEEK`was added in form of

- `CALL PEEK(<addr>, var [,var[,...]])`

It was meant for speedy access binary data, loaded via `CALL LOAD` or some other means, for further use - such as sprite images or sound. As mentioned, TI BASIC was quite advanced, but thus 'special' as well.

---

*1 - I have a hard time finding any reason to implement such.

*2 - Of course statements may be conditioned by an `IF` / `THEN` clause.

*3 - Statements following a `GOTO` on the same line (and `REM` statements) will of course not be executed.

*4 - Yes, it's a 16-byte queue walking one step closer. :))

*5 - Machine programs could be loaded using `CALL LOAD(<name>,<code>)`, which not only handled the usual DATA-read-loops, but also linked the result into BASIC (*6). Invocation with `CALL LINK(<function>, <var>...)` allowed exchange via standard BASIC variables, so no need to PEEK and POKE around. Just call it.

*6 - Which makes it quite different from a POKE or multi byte POKE of other implementations.

Comment: I agree that all this makes sense, and that the language semantics shouldn't prevent PEEK and POKE on the same line. Which is why I remember being surprised. However, I can imagine a BASIC interpreter that would use a common resource for PEEK and POKE (such as a precious pointer in zero page on a 6502). "POKE I," would set the pointer to the destination address, but evaluating the expression "PEEK(I+1)" would clobber the pointer. Trying to meet a deadline to finish the BASIC ROM, just disallow both keywords on the same line, problem solved.

Comment: @Nimloth Why on earth should any programmer of a ROM _add_ code (remember space is scare) to prevent some hypothetical situation that can't be prevented anyway? Peek and poke _is_ intended to handle RAM. What it does is not up to ROM developers. BASIC has no self awareness. Even more by adding a processing mechanic that is alien to the language? Unless you can come up with any _BASIC_ that has this addition, I would think your memory rather mixed that up. Bottom line: With that restriction it wouldn't be BASIC.

Comment: Any chance this was a timing issue?  e.g. reading both paddles on an Apple II could cause interference if you issued the second request too soon after the first.

Comment: Early versions of BASIC were not only limited to one statement per line, but they also required that IF/THEN statements be conditional jumps, rather than allowing a statement following the THEN to be executed conditionally.  It's possible that some version of BASIC had a PEEK statement  rather than a function (vaguely analogous to an input statement), but I don't know of any in particular.

Comment: @supercat Putting speculation onto unsupported speculation wound bring any gain, or does it?

Comment: @Raffzahn: My pain point was that early versions of BASIC were definitely limited to one statement per limt.  I recall reading that TI's Extended BASIC for the TI-994/a used CALL POKE, and CALL was statement rather than a function, but that dialect supported multiple statements per lime even though the non-Extended dialect did not.

Comment: Ups, sorry Raffzahn, I haven't seen that you mentioned the TI-99/4A. I still let my answer as it is as you didn't mention that it was possible to have CALL PEEK/LOAD (and PEEKV/POKEV) in TI-BASIC with the special Mini-Memory module. This has then the 1 statement per line restriction.

Comment: On TI-99/4A there was no PEEK/POKE for the simple reason that there was no accessible memory in the console (128 16bit words that's all). Without the 32K Memory expansion (in reality a 24K+8K expansion), even TI-Extended BASIC didn't provide the PEEK/LOAD/LINK subroutines. As said, there was also the Mini-Memory module that provided 4K battery backed extension and the PEEK/LOAD/LINK calls (+POKEV/PEEKV for video RAM).

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter Sorry, but that reasoning (no memory) makes no sense, as exactly that 256 bytes of memory would be most interesting to be peeked into :))

Comment: @Raffzahn. O, sure for tinkerers it is and I've seen usage of it with small assembly routines etc. but, don't forget how the TI-99 was marketed at that time, nothing outside of TI's control was allowed, considering the user base as children.

Comment: Raffzahn, you appear to have rolled back the edits I made. That is your right but you should be aware that they were made because it seems (at least to me) that English is not your primary language. My intent was to simply "clean up" the test so that is was more readable, hence making it more useful, so I'm sorry if that annoyed or bothered you (if indeed it did). But, as stated, it is *your* answer so you can modify it as you see fit. I won't attempt to further modify your answers but I cannot in all honesty upvote it in its current form due to its limitations.

Comment: @paxdiablo If you care to look close, I did not roll back but kept your changes, except for when you changed meaning - removing the 'code walking' part  and changing the slash into or - and unnecessary blanks. Look it up. Beside, it would be rather helpful if you could point out what part you think is factual wrong and/or a limitation as you call it (I would like to believe you're judgement is about content not form).

Comment: @paxdiablo P.S.:  I'm always grateful for [help in spelling and gramer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/682).

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter: I would think that being able to manipulate data into the 16K DRAM that's accessed through the video chip could be useful for a wide variety of purposes.  If one wanted to programmatically generate character-shape data, I would think a function to write a byte at an address in video memory would be faster than code to build a hex string and then use CALL CHAR on that.  Philosophically it may have been preferred to let BASIC handle everything, but a PEEK/POKE equivalent for video memory could have been very useful.

Comment: @supercat yes that's true. That's what the Mini-memory module provided. Besides the CALL PEEK/LOAD for CPU memory it provided the CALL PEEKV/POKEV for TI-Basic to access video memory. If you follow some of the links I gave in my answer/comments you can see examples where it is used to do exactly what you described.